# When does zero correlation imply independence? (apart from joint normal)

Tags: probability, distributions, correlation, normal-distribution, independence

Is there a class of distributions (other than joint normal) such that the statement is true? In other words, is there a class of distributions under which zero correlation implies independence? Can we impose a general condition on the distributions such that the statement is true?