# Example of a parametric family of distributions that always has dependence on among its variables

Tags: distributions, independence, example, parametric

Inspired by [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555103/when-does-zero-correlation-imply-independence-apart-from-joint-normal), I would like an example of a parametric family of distributions such that there is dependence for all choices of parameters. The family could be infinite or finite, but I would like the support to be infinite.

Can such an example be constructed?

Comment: Let $X, Y$  satisfy $X^2 + Y^2 =1$. Whatever joint you define, $X, Y$  will be dependent.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Ah yes, an equality constraint! Very good example.